# macbook: how to close the inbuilt display without closing the lid

Tags: macbook-pro, display

i am having my work setup by connecting MacBook M2 Pro (2023) connected to external monitors. I dont want the inbuilt display to be on when connected to external monitors.

Closing the lid works, but it occasionally runs the laptop hot. I heard of a magnet trick to simulate the lid closure, but unable to find the spot for my version.

Anybody knows?